# rails 3 caching - is there a gem for that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Good day! Currently i'm thinking about implementing caching on a website.
I've read an article about it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html
What i'm wondering is there a gem for caching rails app ?
Yes, rails provides many ways to do that, but what i'm interested about is there a gem or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your options : 
[render-cachce](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fryanb%2Frender-caching%2F&ei=fGg8UKbMJKWTiAKJ4oCIDw&usg=AFQjCNEnwUtQvH_BBMHl9W8xmi9eFom8Ng)
[rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached)

Comment: Thanks, the second one looks more up  to date .

Answer (score 2):

DHH recently spoke about a new approach to caching ("russian doll caching") that 37Signals used in Basecamp Next.

They even released a gem for it, which you can [see here](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests).

To see the video where he is explaining it and showing off Basecamp next, [watch it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkLVl3gpJP4&t=33m).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of gems avaialble for implementing cache mechanism in rails, the lists are memcached, cache, memcache-client.
For your reference follow the rubygems.org, then search gems like cache.